# Question on Series in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

The Question: Is it possible to find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} {a_n}^{2}$ converges however $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^{2}}{n}$ diverges.

I am having a hard time coming up with examples. I am guessing we have to use terms with $ln(x)$ in it. Are there any examples?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: $a_n^2/n\le a_n^2.$

Answer (score 3):

No because $$\sum_n\frac{a_n^2}{n} \leq \sum_na_n^2<\infty$$